# Disable TitledPane Expand

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How I can disable TitledPane expand?

```
TitledPane pane = new TitledPane("Connections", content);
```

I can't find any information about this on Google.

Comment: Did you try `pane.setDisable(true);` ?

Comment: I think he's probably looking for `TitledPane#setCollapsible(boolean)`.

Comment: Indeed, good point...

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to google, you can simply check javadoc or Ctrl+space will show you all methods for that class. To answer your question its

titledPane.setCollapsible(false);